# Chrome doesn't set cookie while IE does

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies

Chrome doesn't set cookie returned by express server while IE does. I'm tryint to do this on my localhost but actually i have already configured "app.com" mapping to 127.0.0.1 in my windows hosts file.

Response headers example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://app.com
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 10 Jul 2016 08:52:22 GMT
set-cookie:connect.sid=s%3AXoykypZiNMoSvH_L7nH7SqeqLydEQSHK.770Fk%2Fc4pGMu%2Bi%2BtQwQr%2BWbHkkAk%2FOFMYVlmMwzqU1o; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 11 Jul 2016 08:52:22 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Express settings:

```
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

module.exports = function (app, express, config, mongoose) {

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://app.com');

        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Cookie');

        // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
        // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

        // Pass to next layer of middleware
        next();
    });

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('coockie is:', req.cookies);
        next();
    });

    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: false,
        secret: config.sessionsSecretToken,
        cookie: {
            secure: false,
            domain: '',
            path: '/',
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        },
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    }));

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..' , 'public')));

};
```